# How can I write a Django custom save method that will get or create a foreign key before saving

Tags: django

I have following Django models for City and State set up like this:

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=2)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    state = models.ForeignKey( State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True )
```

I'm importing json company data that includes NAME, CITY, and STATE. It looks like this:

```
{'NAME': 'Company Name', 'ADDRESS': '123 Main St.', 'CITY': 'Bethel', 'STATE': 'Connecticut'}
```

I'm trying to set up a custom save method to my Company object that would get or create the necessary City object upon creating or updating the company. Creation of a City object will, in turn, require the getting or creating of a State object.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey( City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True )
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.city, created = City.objects.get_or_create(name=city)

        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since the state field in City is not required, I'm starting with just trying to create the city.

In my code, I'm creating the new Company instance like this:

```
        company, created = Company.objects.update_or_create(
            name=p['NAME],
            defaults = {
                'address1': p.get('ADDRESS1', None),
                'address2': p.get('ADDRESS2', None),
                'city': p.get('CITY', None),
                'zipcode': p.get('ZIP', None),
            }
```

But Django is returning this error:

```
Cannot assign "'Bethel'": "Company.city" must be a "City" instance.
```

Comment: How are you passing the city to your new company instance? can you post the code that you are using to create a new `Company` instance?

Comment: Good question. I've updated my code to include the creation of a new Company instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this part: `'city': p.get('CITY', None)`

You have a field named `city` in your `Company` model which is a foreignkey to `City` model while `p.get('CITY', None)` will returns either the city string if available or `None` if not which doesn't meet the requirements for a foreignkey field.

So you either have to get/create the city instance in your view and pass it to `city` field or you have to change the field name passed to `save` method and access it there.

I recommend passing the `City` instance in your view instead of overriding the save method which can cause extra complication especially when you change your model and you forget about it.

Comment: I generally handle things in the view. But I was thinking perhaps it would be cleaner to do in the save method or as a signal because I've got about a dozen json files I'm importing into various tables all related through a variety of foreign keys. Was hoping to keep my view as clean as possible.

Comment: Sure, if you think it's the better idea. just pass the city name by a different name and you should be good to go.

Comment: You are correct. I got it working, but this is rapidly coming to complex to maintain. I'm going to use your good advice to handle this in the view.